# bad_alloc exception when using imwrite to write ppm file in Opencv/C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, exception, opencv, bad-alloc

I am simply trying to save a Mat as a ppm image. I am able to read the ppm and load it into a Mat. The part of code that is causing the error is:

```
    //  Display Image
    namedWindow("Comparison", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Comparison", comparisonMat);
    waitKey();

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
    compression_params.push_back(1);

    imwrite("Comparison.ppm",comparisonMat,compression_params);
```

It builds successfully but when it comes to writing the file, I get the following error:

"Unhandled exception at 0x76b2c41f in HW.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0018f280.."

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:
I made it work by doing the following:

```
IplImage* writeImage=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)comparisonMat);
cvSaveImage("Comparison.ppm", writeImage);
```

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: @Ralph its 1536x1024. I tried saving a smaller version (half size). Still gave the same error.

Comment: Some suggestions: Try to pass an empty vector as `compression_params`. Make sure the image is a 8-bit single-channel or 24-bit 3-channel image. I've found that OpenCV sometimes does very strange things when you try to pass some unusual parameter types. For debugging purposes you may want to trivially fill `comparisonMat` with zeros. What OpenCV version do you have, by the way?

Comment: The image is 24-bit 3-channel. I tried passing an empty param vector as well as writing an all zeroes Mat but neither changed anything. I'm using OpenCV v2.1.